# How to make a shared library in Android?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I'm working on a Android embed system, and have a make a service library for all app installed in the system.

This library is shared, I mean it doesn't packed in the other apk, it's a standalone apk and when install it, other app can use library.

You can imagine like openCV app example from version 2.4. User have to install OpenCV Manager and other app have to import it, otherwise it will throw Exception and require you to install this app. It also have same behaviour like `<uses-library>` tag in manifest but no instruction how to do it.
Sơ anyway to solve it?

PS: I have search everywhere but all the post is about static lib use Android Studio. Shared Library found only use Eclipse and for a long time ago. At new version, openCV sample is converted to Android Studio and use normal import.

Comment: Probably you are looking for content providers and broadcast listeners

Comment: @kelvin Yes I know about content Provider and Broadcast, but there are so many API and Model that Provider can't do it. My Service use AIDL to provide Api for other app. But also about Model, we have to copy it into other app.
Also I known about external lib like OpenCV Manager does, why Android Studio can't do it?